# Наследование конструкторов при nocopyable

Tags: c++, boost

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что мне необходимо наследовать конструктор с параметром класса boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket
Вот код, который у меня не компилируется:

```
io_service service;
class MainSocket : public ip::tcp::socket
{
public:
    set<std::shared_ptr<MainSocket>>::iterator iterrator;
    ~MainSocket();
    MainSocket(io_service ser) : ip::tcp::socket(ser){}
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<MainSocket> SOCKET_PTR;
...
SOCKET_PTR socket(new MainSocket(service)); //Ошибка
```

Сам текст ошибки:

```
    ../../Загрузки/boost_1_61_0/boost/asio/detail/noncopyable.hpp:32:3: error: 'boost::asio::detail::noncopyable::noncopyable(const boost::asio::detail::noncopyable&)' is private
   noncopyable(const noncopyable&);
   ^
In file included from ../miniserv/main.cpp:10:0:
../../Загрузки/boost_1_61_0/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:185:7: error: within this context
 class io_service
       ^
```

Использование C++11 C++14 допустимо. Как объявить наследование конструктора, что бы ошибки компиляции не возникало и код отработал как надо? Компилятор G++

Comment: Вопрос решен. Код: MainSocket() : ip::tcp::socket(service){}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка ведь должна быть ясна: `io_service` нельзя копировать, он наследуется от `noncopyable`. Измените то, как Вы передаёте объект `io_service` в Ваш класс(ссылка, указатель, умный указатель и т.п.) и ошибка уйдёт. К наследованию это не имеет никакого отношения.